# Using an Angularjs Promise on a objectID

Tags: angularjs, svg, angular-promise

I am trying to build a dynamic SVG chart.  Each object in the chart has an ID.  All works well, the labels and and other objects draw fine, but Firfox's  console logfile is full of the following errors:

```
Error: [$interpolate:interr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.2/$interpolate/interr?p0=%7B%7B(getText1Wid…eError%3A%20Cannot%20read%20property%20'getComputedTextLength'%20of%20null
```

This error refers to the following code:

```
   $scope.getText1Width = function (item) {
        if (typeof document.getElementById('text1-' + item) != 'undefined') {
            return document.getElementById('text1-' + item).getComputedTextLength()};    // Error Here
        return null;
    };
```

There are other functions that are similar and generate the same class of error:

```
$scope.getRecAbsLoc,
$scope.getTransData,
$scope.resizeSVG
```

What I would like to do is us a Promise to delay the evaluation of this code until the object referenced by the ID is rendered.

The theory is that for each 'item' in a list defined on $scope, a box, text and connecting lines are created.

Here is the template for the SVG:

---

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="btn-xs btn-primary"
                ng-click="popDrawing('sm')">
            Enlarge
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="my-scroll-div1">
        <div class="my-scroll-div2 container">

            <svg id="svg-head" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                <defs>
                    <marker id="markerCircle" markerWidth="8" markerHeight="8" refx="5" refy="5">
                        <circle cx="5" cy="5" r="2" style="stroke: none; fill: inherit;"/>
                    </marker>

                    <marker id="markerArrowStart" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5" refx="0" refy="2.5" orient="auto">
                        <path d="M2.5,0 v5 l-2.5,-2.5 Z " style="fill: inherit; "/>
                    </marker>
                    <marker id="markerArrowEnd" markerWidth="5" markerHeight="5" refx="2.5" refy="2.5" orient="auto">
                        <path d="M0,0 v5 l2.5,-2.5 Z " style="fill: inherit; "/>
                    </marker>
                </defs>

                <g
                        ng-attr-transform="translate({{nD.rxOffset*$index+1}},{{2+$index*(nD.height+nD.ryOffset)}})"
                        ng-repeat="item in $parent.productVersionsTested |orderBy: '-plRank'"
                        ng-attr-id="trans-{{item.pvNum}}"
                        text-anchor="middle"
                        class="my-box"

                        >
                    <rect
                            ng-attr-height={{nD.height}}
                            ng-attr-width={{(getText1Width(item.pvNum)+(nD.hPad*2))}}
                            ng-attr-id="rect-{{item.pvNum}}"
                            class="my-box"
                            >
                        {{resizeSVG('rect-'+item.pvNum)}}
                    </rect>
                    <text
                            ng-attr-x={{((getText1Width(item.pvNum)+(nD.hPad*2))/2)}}
                            ng-attr-y={{(nD.height/2)-5}}
                            ng-attr-id="text1-{{item.pvNum}}"
                            class="my-text"
                            >
                        <tspan>{{item.plName}}</tspan>
                    </text>
                    <text
                            ng-attr-x={{((getText1Width(item.pvNum)+(nD.hPad*2))/2)}}
                            ng-attr-y={{(nD.height/2)+10}}
                            ng-attr-id="text2-{{item.pvNum}}"
                            class="my-text"
                            >
                        <tspan>{{item.pvVerString}}</tspan>
                    </text>
                    <g ng-repeat="line in item.plMatchList">
                        <path
                                ng-attr-d="{{buildPath($parent.$index,$index,line)}}"
                                ng-attr-style="{{buildStyle($parent.$index,$index,line)}}"
                                />
                    </g>
                </g>
            </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

As always, thank you in advance for your help with this.

Comment: try wrapping in `$timeout` and make sure to include `$timeout` as dependency in directive you are calling this from. Will defer until digests are complete doing this way